# Is it possible to do projection in Google Big Query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a query (due to restrictions, it is using Legacy SQL) that produces a column that is the rolling average of last 3 days of sale (excluding today)

```
SELECT 
id, date, sales, AVG(sales) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date RANGE BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS projected_sale
FROM tableA
```

tableA

```
+-------+---------+---------+
| id    |  date   | sales   |
+-------+---------+---------+
| 1     | 01-01-17|    5    |
| 1     | 01-02-17|    6    |
| 1     | 01-03-17|    7    |
| 1     | 01-04-17|    10   |
+-------+---------+---------+
```

The query produces

```
+-------+---------+---------+--------------+
| id    |  date   | sales   |projected_sale|
+-------+---------+---------+--------------+
| 1     | 01-01-17|    5    |     .        |
| 1     | 01-02-17|    6    |     .        |
| 1     | 01-03-17|    7    |     .        |
| 1     | 01-04-17|    10   |     6        |
+-------+---------+---------+--------------+
```

Since the average is excluding the current row, theoretically I can project the sale for 01-05-17 using the sales from (01-02 to 01-04). However since tableA doesn't actually have a entry with date 01-05-17, my query stops at 01-04-17 as the last row.

Is what I am trying to do possible in Big Query?

Thank you

Comment: btw. what are those restrictions you keep mentioning about Legacy SQL  - why you think you stuck with it? would be great to know so we might be able to help you to get freedom :o)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant, We need to use the function CURRENT_USER() at the end of out query (excluded for simplification purpose), I don't believe standard SQL has this.

Comment: ok. I see. While i am typing answer on this question - check your previous question - i answered it

Comment: The equivalent function is `SESSION_USER`.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard I didn't realize, definitely should have read the documentation more carefully. Thank you!

Comment: i had to take few extra coffee I think - have no idea how i've missed that one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think using `RANGE` is incorrect here - it should be `ROWS` instead

Anyway, below is an example for BigQuery Legacy SQL that demonstrates how to achieve result you need.

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT 
  id, dt, sales, 
  AVG(sales) OVER (
    PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt 
    ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
  ) AS projected_sale
FROM tableA, (SELECT 1 id, '01-05-17' dt, 0 sales)
```

As you can see here you just simply adding (UNION ALL - comma in Kegacy SQL) that missing day. Of course you can transform that one such that it will add such missing row for all id's

Nevetherless - hope this is a good starting point for you

You can test / play with it using dummy data as in your question

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT 
  id, dt, sales, 
  AVG(sales) OVER (
    PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt 
    ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
  ) AS projected_sale
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT 1 id, '01-01-17' dt, 5 sales),
    (SELECT 1 id, '01-02-17' dt, 6 sales),
    (SELECT 1 id, '01-03-17' dt, 7 sales),
    (SELECT 1 id, '01-04-17' dt, 10 sales)
) tableA, (SELECT 1 id, '01-05-17' dt, 0 sales)
```

with result as

```sql
Row id  dt          sales   projected_sale   
1   1   01-01-17    5       null     
2   1   01-02-17    6       5.0  
3   1   01-03-17    7       5.5  
4   1   01-04-17    10      6.0  
5   1   01-05-17    0       7.0
```

Comment: please consider voting up if answer helped!

Comment: Hey @Mikhail, you mentioned that I can transform the union all to include all ids, does that mean I manually type out a extra select statement for every id? or is there a more simpler way?

Comment: of course adding them manually makes not much practical sense. what I meant is you can extend existing script to make it work. let's say you can get all distinct id's and cross join them on missing current (or whatever day you need) so this will replace - `(SELECT 1 id, '01-05-17' dt, 0 sales)` - if still issue for you to make this work  - please ask/post new specific question and I (or someone else) will answer this one too :o)  But, please, first try by yourself